# How can I make the material time picker appear under just under the input? (Append to input)

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker, angular-material-datetimepicker

I have been looking searching to find anything related to this. but no nothing.

```html
<div>
    <input [ngxTimepicker]="picker" >
    <ngx-material-timepicker #picker></ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```

This is what I am using. I want the time-picker to be under the input component instead of a popup. which means. instead of taking the full screen, I want that to be open just under the input component

Comment: What exactly is a "drop down"?

Comment: like whenever we click the input there will be a picker popping up. can we change the pop up to dropdown (not like in the middle of the screen big popup) instead the same picker just under the input field

Comment: A drop down typically refers to a `<select>`. But you just want to change the location of the popup?

Comment: yes. kind of. instead of taking the full screen, I want that to be open just under the input component

Comment: So you want that dialog with clock display under input right?

Comment: yes. sorry for my english. it's not my native language

Answer (score 1):

found a solution

'''

```
<div class="ngx-timepicker">
    <input [ngxTimepicker]="appendedToInput" aria-label="Append to input"
           placeholder="Append to input" readonly>
    <ngx-material-timepicker
        #appendedToInput
        [appendToInput]="true">
    </ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```

'''